# Math logic Triangle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers, number-theory

[image]

**Rules**

- Arrange numbers from 1 to 15 to the white triangles.
- A op B = result 
  [image]
- Green triangle means 2 numbers of its side are adjacent numbers.
- (-) means find the difference
- (/) means divide the bigger number with the lower number.

**Example** 
[image]

Comment: Does each number occur once, or are we allowed to enter them multiple time?

Comment: @MikeLimburg : each number occur once

Comment: @JamalSenjaya , did you invent this problem or did you take it from somewhere ? If it is the latter then it would be nice to know of the source. Thanks

Comment: @HemantAgarwal I invented it, by a little programming If you want more like it, just browse my puzzles here at PSE.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya , can I post a video solution of this puzzle on YouTube for this ?  This is my channel https://youtube.com/channel/UCrXHekv4IVDiTGAF09LcjaQ

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Oh, yes sure. Feel free to do that. You can also use my other puzzle to your youtube channel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following a well-designed trail of clues leads to...

> [image]

That trail begins at the two division **/** triangles
that both include the given **3**
and must each include consecutive numbers.
 
The only possibilities are  {**2**,**3**,6} and {**3**,**4**,12},
which fairly rapidly sift to:

• Use up 5 of the 7 available even numbers.

• Force a pattern of odd and even numbers among the remaining cells.

> [image]

The 2 remaining even numbers fit only one way and:

• Daisy-chain upward to fill out all but the bottom row.

• Leave a set of numbers with only one pair that can
       produce consecutive numbers in the bottom right triangle.

> [image]

The bottom left corner shakes out from there.
(And, yeah, the original path to solution involved some
 unnecessary trial and error.)

Comment: I hit the answer button, write the text "This is my solution", copy the picture from my local machine, then PSE says an answer was just added. I swear a lot, check the solution, is the same as what I found, swear again then upvote. Then swear again. Good job. ##@!#@(*&@# (censored)

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOooooo, Marius! You can be sure it has gone the other way, too, for both of us no doubt.

Comment: @humn : Still waiting for your logic explanation.

Comment: Very funny, @Jamal Senjaya, another very well clued puzzle in any case, by the way

Comment: @humn : Thank you, I will try to create many more.

Comment: Lucky to have the chance, @Jamal Senjaya, and missed out by seconds on a couple of your others, including your $n{-}1$dreth

Answer (score 5):

You actually get to the same solution with more work even if you don't read what green triangles mean.

> That 3 you can see can be a part of (6, 2), (12, 4) and (15, 5) if you forget about green triangle rule. Due to subtraction below, 15, 5 cannot be on the bottom and (12,4) could be only if there is (14, 2) or (13, 1) below. Now if 12 is on the right, it would require +3 to make 15 = not possible, so 12 would need to be on the left. There is a plus sign too, so either 13 or 14 appears on the top and both 1 and 2 are used, meaning the other pair has to be (15, 5), and 11 is there on the right. Now, say there is 13 below - it needs 1 to make 12 and 9 to make 4 (14 would need 2 and 10). But to make 1 out of 2, or 2 out of 1, you need number 3, which is already used.

So, we have

> 6 and 2 are below 3. We have 3 options for the other division and that subtraction: (bottom towards top) 
>  6, 2, 10; 3, 12; 4 
>  6, 2, 13; 3, 15; 5 
>  2, 6, 9; 3, 15; 5

Let's start with the last one:

> 6 cannot be made as 7-1, as you will not be able to use 7. (7+2 or 7-5 both duplicate a number). It cannot be made as 8-2, 9-3, 11-5, 12-6 obviously and 13-7 is eliminated for the same reason as 7-1. 10-4 has the problem of making 9 which would require 4+5. So, 14-8 is the only option. Bottom right is 1, then 8, then 14, then 12 - to make 2. We have 4, 7, 10, 11, 13 left. But we cannot make top right corner - no 2 numbers are 5 apart. OK, so this option is eliminated.

Next:

> Let's consider 6, 2, 13 now. Under 2 we could have (7, 9) => 1, 7, 9, 4, (8, 10) => impossible, (9, 11) => impossible, (10, 12) => 4, 10, 12, 1 or (12, 14) => 8, 14, 12, 1.

Now:

> First option leads to 8, 10, 11, 12, 14 for remaining numbers, which again doesn't have a gap of 5. Second one has 7, 8, 9, 11, 14. So, 14 on the top, 9 to the left of 5. We would need 12 to make that 9 and we don't have it. Too bad. And the third ends up with 4, 7, 9, 10, 11. 9 on top, 4 under it, 7 next. And now we require 1 which we don't have. So, this doesn't work either.

Finally:

> We know the central part of the whole triangle is 6, 2, 10; 3, 12; 4. Now, how to make 10? (1, 9) is the only option. (2, 8), (3, 7) and (4, 6) are impossible. 9 needs to be right with 1 on the left or we won't make 2. Fill in 13, 7 to make 2 and 6. Note that remaining numbers are 5, 8, 11, 14, 15. To have difference of 4, 15 on top and 11 below are required. 14 to make 11, 8 to make 14 and 5 to make 8, and we have our unique solution.